# futon web access after adding admin username/password error unauthorized

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I have added admin user and password for curl/php data creation. Now Futon is not letting me run the Temporary View "Error: unauthorized: You are not a db or server admin".

Comment: I have undo the changes, it worked, but that's not a solution. Any tip will be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried logging in after adding your admin user?

Comment: yeah, you need to log in after creating an admin user

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the local.ini file in \etc\couchdb directory. Edit the field "require_valid_user = true" under [couch_httpd_auth] header and set that field to true.

Restart your couchdb instance and this time Futon will prompt you to enter the username and password.

After that you can make any change you want.